# Be kind, show a preview of the font

Tags: discussion, font-identification

When answering a question with a font link please take the time and make a quality answer.  Remember we are visual people!  A link only answer with no further details will be removed if the link goes down.  Please add the following:

- Screenshot of the font
- Name of the font
- Creator of the font
- Name of the source (ie: fonts.com & fontsquirrel)

If you dont have enough rep to post the image someone can still come by and embed the image for you.  This extra detail produces better answers and we are encouraged to upvote your efforts.  Also, if the link goes down we don't have to delete your answer and/or you wont receive any downvotes.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot explaining your concerns, please?

Comment: Im sorry what do you mean screenshot?  Do you mean an example of a good post?

Comment: I figured the Sith had a weak sense of humor.

Comment: I think this is good practice for the future but I don't think it is a viable use of members' time to revive font ID questions that are over a year old to ask people to update their answer with a screenshot considering that font ID questions' worth is kind of debatable in the first place.

Comment: Then are you ok if answers are removed if the links were to go down?

Comment: @Vader It was a sarcastic joke, no doubt. Anyway, I'm not sure if such answers would always *have* to be that detailed, but I can relate to your way of thinking. Doesn't hurt to keep people sharp about these things.

Comment: I knew it was a joke but I had to make sure.  Just trying to make GD.SE a better place and encourage better answers.  Everyone that has made an edit after I have asked I have upvoted because it is a better answer and not a link only answer.

Comment: @Vader Yes. I  think most of them will just end up cluttering the site anyways, except for rare occasions. Do we have any stats as to how useful these questions are to members others than the ones who ask them? (do these questions get searched at all?)

Comment: Stop questioning the validity of the suggestion of the Dark Lord and add a frakking screenshot!